# MySQL wildcard matching with concat

Tags: mysql, sql-like, concatenation

I have this code which returns the result I want:

```
SELECT CONCAT('#', id, ' ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ' (', company, ')') AS result FROM client_detail
```

Here are the results:

```
#1 James Hadley (OpenBill)
#2 Lucinda Hadley (Make a Squish)
```

But when trying to search in the same string when using LIKE (I want to search for a variable string anywhere inside the above results), I get no output and no errors:

```
SELECT CONCAT('#', id, ' ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ' (', company, ')') AS result FROM client_detail WHERE CONCAT('#', id, ' ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ' (', company, ')') LIKE '%jam%' ORDER BY id ASC
```

I am right to use the LIKE operand, or is there a better/correct way of searching inside the result?

Comment: What happens if you change the 'where' clause to a 'having'? Im not sure those values exist for concat-ing yet.

Comment: This is valid SQL, and should get you what you want. What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: @tomtheman5: "*I get no output and no errors*".  However, I do agree that the OP should be getting what he wants: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2734e/1/0 (unless the connection's collation is case-sensitive).

Comment: Yep it was case-sensitive - that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `CONCAT` statement will use the system default for collations. If your table is defined as *UTF-8* but your system is *latin1* then your `LIKE` statement may choose a case-sensitive collation.

Force a case-insensitive match using `LOWER`
(Using `HAVING` to take advantage of your alias `result`):

```
SELECT CONCAT('#',id,' ',firstname,' ',lastname,' (', company, ')') AS result
  FROM client_detail 
HAVING LOWER(result) LIKE '%jam%'    
 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Or use a COLLATION (will depend on your system)

```
...
HAVING result LIKE '%jam%' COLLATE latin1_general_ci
...
```

Comment: "*MySQL's `LIKE` statement is case-sensitive.*" - No it isn't.  It depends on the collation of the operands.

Comment: @eggyal Although LIKE isn't case sensitive - in this case it appears to be. Please try this example and see for yourself.

Comment: In my case it does appear to be case-sentitive. I'll use the above code to convert the case and tidy the whole thing up. Thank you very much!

Comment: My mysql version (5.0.83) defaults to a latin1 based `COLLATION` with `CONCAT` even though the system and table are defined as `utf8_general_ci`. You could try using a latin1 case-insensitive COLLATION like `HAVING result LIKE '%jam%' COLLATE latin1_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than converting case, which is an expensive operation, you could instead force use of a case-insensitive collation:

```
SELECT   CONCAT('#', id, ' ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ' (', company, ')')
           AS result
FROM     client_detail
WHERE    CONCAT('#', id, ' ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ' (', company, ')')
           LIKE '%jam%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ORDER BY id ASC
```

However, this is still extremely expensive as it requires that the concatenation and search is performed for every record in the table: indexing is useless.

Perhaps it's possible to rephrase the query to take better advantage of indexes (if they exist):

```
SELECT   CONCAT('#', id, ' ', firstname, ' ', lastname, ' (', company, ')')
           AS result
FROM     client_detail
WHERE    firstname LIKE 'jam%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
      OR lastname  LIKE 'jam%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
      OR company   LIKE 'jam%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Albeit this query only searches for `'jam'` at the start of each field, rather than being some substring within them.

Comment: The first solution here works much better actually. Thank you!

Comment: @user1497049: You might want to investigate why you were defaulting to a case-sensitive collation.  Perhaps check the table design and your connection settings.